# How to change only one specific object in array of objects in functional style?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, code-readability

Let's assume we want to create some very readable code which does the next:

1. iterates through all elements of list
2. changes all of them equally except *only one* specific element (even though more than one element can satisfy search criteria)
3. return this list with changed elements
4. uses _.underscore power

For example, i want to add property `isChosen` with `true` value only to the first element which has `hasRoom` property, other element should get `false` value for this new property `hasRoom`

Here is code created using _.underscore lib:

```
  var i = 0
  var changedList = []
  _.each(list, function(el) {
    if (el.hasRoom && i === 0) {
      _.extend(el, { isChosen: true })
      i++
    } else {
      _.extend(el, { isChosen: false })
    }
    changedList.push(el)
  })
```

This code works, but I think there can be better way of making same, maybe with _.chain()?

So, as input we can have

```
[
    {hasRoom: false}, 
    {hasRoom: true}, 
    {hasRoom: true}
]
```

And as result we should get

```
[
    {hasRoom: false, isChosen: false}, 
    {hasRoom: true,  isChosen: true}, 
    {hasRoom: true,  isChosen: false}
]
```

Comment: Do you _have_ to create a new object? As for the code-readability tag, why use a number when you can use a boolean?

Comment: @user1066946 this code chunk is inside of function addPropertyToOnlyOneElement(list) and it should return changed list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution modifies the function that sets the isChosen:

```
function notChosen(place){
  return false;
}

function chosen(place){
  if( !place.hasRoom ) return notChosen(place);
  setChosen = notChosen;
  return true;
}

var setChosen = chosen;

_.each(places, function(place){
    place.isChosen = setChosen(place);
});
```

The if statement will only be executed until the first place with a room is found.

Answer (score 2):

```
var _ = require("underscore");
var data = [{hasRoom: true}, {hasRoom: true}, {}], found = false;

_.each(data, function(currentObject) {
    _.defaults(currentObject, {isChosen: false});
    if (found === false && currentObject.hasRoom) {
        found = currentObject.isChosen = true;
    }
});

console.log(data);
```

**Output**

```
[ { hasRoom: true, isChosen: true },
  { hasRoom: true, isChosen: false },
  { isChosen: false } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method typically called `first` to find the first element that matches your criteria:

```
function first (array, filter_function) {
    var index, len = array.length;
    for (index = 0; index < len; index += 1) {
        if (filter_function(array[index], index)) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

rooms = [
    { hasRoom: false }, 
    { hasRoom: true }, 
    { hasRoom: true }
];

free_room = first(rooms, function (room) {
    return room.hasRoom;
});
if (free_room === -1) {
    throw "Dilbert lied!";
}
rooms[free_room].isChosen = true;
```

---

Note that `_js` also defines a `first` function on an Array, but it's more for a `cat` or `head` function. You can argue about semantics.

Comment: You are putting everything in the global scope, also there is a for each in JavaScript

Comment: There is no for each in JavaScript; only `for-in`. We're dealing with Arrays not Objects, so `for-in` is not needed. This is a proof-of-concept code to demonstrate how `first` works, take your global scope concerns to places where they are relevant. Your comment is wrong and misleading.

Comment: Are you sure your code has better readability then code in question?

Comment: There is `Array.prototype.forEach` and also the for in loop, before you edited the question you put every variable in the answer on the global scope, and the answer is twice as long as the question.

Comment: Sorry I use Chrome, didn't know you were running IE8

Comment: `forEach` will always loop over _all_ elements in the list, since `first` is only concerned with the first match there is no need to loop over all elements. I added the link so at least we're not making baseless claims, I was not aware it is now well supported. Browser support for functions changes over time.

Answer (score 1):

In a functional style, you'd do this:

```
// type: [a] -> (a -> Bool -> b) -> (a -> Bool) -> [b]
function changeFirstinList(list, change, predicate) {
    var first = true;
    return _.map(list, function(el) {
        return change(el, first && !(first = !predicate(el)));
    });
}

changeFirstinList([
    {hasRoom: false}, 
    {hasRoom: true}, 
    {hasRoom: true}
], function(el, isFirstwithpred) {
    return {hasRoom: el.hasRoom, isChosen: isFirstwithpred};
}, function(el) {
    return el.hasRoom;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally my code started to look like this:

```
function addChosenPropertyToFirstElementWithRooms(hotels) {
  var found = false
  return _.map(list, function(el) {
    return _.merge(el, { isChosen: isFirstElementWithRooms(el) })
  })

  function isFirstHotelWithRooms(el) {
    return found ? false : found = el.hasRoom
  }
}
```

And usage of function is easy

```
var changedList = addChosenPropertyToFirstElementWithRooms(originalList)
```